# Can we feel sinusoid?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, wave, sine

If we have a signal of 1 or 2Hz, can our skin receptors feel that sinewave, if that sinewave has aproppriate voltage level?

Comment: Of course, at the approriate voltage level, you can feel any frequency

Comment: At 1 Megavolt, you will feel it, anywhere from DC to daylight.

Comment: This is a dumb question.

Comment: Note that 'TENS' units, or muscle stimulators, and neural stimulators, use square waves with narrow pulses, and intensity is adjusted by current-not voltage. Frequency range is 5HZ to about 1KHZ, at the discretion of the therapist/doctor.

Comment: When someone can feel electricity, it usually means they're about to be shocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "feel the sinewave" to the extent that, if variations in voltage are slow enough, then there will be a change in sensation as voltage and/or current vary across a certain range of values.

The actual signal amplitude range where variations will be felt will vary with points of application, skin resistance, person involved and more. Very low voltage signals may not be felt at all. Very high amplitude signals (eg 300 V peak sine wave at 1 Hz). would probably be felt as if 300V DC with polarity changed every 0.5 seconds was applied -you MAY feel the zero crossings as 2 Hz pulses amidst the pain.

However, if you apply a signal such that at peak voltage you get significant but not overposering muscle contractions then you are liable to feel the variation in contractions at a 2 Hz rate. 2Hz for a 1 Hz signal as positive or negative 1/2 cycles will probably have much the same effects).

Answer (score 2):

It should be obvious that the answer is "yes".  At some voltage applied to your skin, it can burn the skin, cause cardiac arrest, or even evaporate your whole body into a cloud of greasy black smoke, depending on what two points on your skin the voltage is applied.  Clearly you can feel lesser effects than that.

Comment: I expect he intends "feel the sinewave" to mean something like "feel changes as the voltage amplitude varies. So, at low enough frequencies and within certain voltage and/or current limits the variations in voltage could be sensed.